# Implementing IGListKit in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, iglistkit

I've been building an app with SwiftUI, targeting iOS 15 and have come across a super cool API called [IGListKit](https://instagram.github.io/IGListKit/index.html) and would love to implement it into my SwiftUI App.

I don't know much about building views the classic Swift way, but I have a very simple idea.

I'm *assuming* I can create a `UIViewRepresentable` of IGListKit and feed props back and forth from my SwiftUI Views to the Swift *controller?*

I'm unable to find any implementations online and was wondering if it was possible before I attempted to integrate it. I would also appreciate any tips on what I'll need to know before I can properly integrate IGListKit into a SwiftUI app.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI on iOS 16 List is now is backed by UICollectionView (previously UITableView)

Comment: @meers
I face the same situation as yours, just wondering how did it go through with your IGListKit implementation. Any update will help.